# GHC - constraint in type signature invalid

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-signature

I'm trying to load the following definition

```
data NestedList a = Elem a | List [NestedList a]
flatten :: (NestedList a) => a -> [a]
flatten (Elem x) = [x]
```

But GHC is giving an error

```
Expected a constraint, but 'NestedList a' has kind '*'
In the type signature for 'flatten'
```

Is there something missing or invalid in the type signature?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part before `=>` is a constraint and must contain type classes, while `NestedList` is just a type. What you wanted to write is

```
flatten :: NestedList a -> [a]
```